# Do periodical subscriptions through Apple differ from direct subscriptions?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-appstore, news.app

I have the iOS app from a major newspaper. When I am in the newspaper’s iOS app, if I click on subscriptions, I'm taken to the iOS subscriptions panel, part of system preferences. There I can get six months subscription to the newspaper for a certain price. When I go to the newspaper’s website I see they are offering a digital subscription, which it says includes the app, at a considerably lower price. It may be that this less expensive subscription is in some way different, but I don’t see how.  I’m confused as to how this works, and the price difference.

How do subscriptions purchased through iOS differ from those purchased directly?

Comment: Subscriptions depend on the app/publisher and their relationship with Apple. What newspaper? You may then get a response from someone with direct experience.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's just marketing.  You are a captive customer, so they don't have to offer you the same discount.  Also, generic offers, such as the website offer are normally for new customers only.  Sometimes there is fine print about the special being for a few months only and then the price goes up.  You could ask for support from the newspaper.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).